# RDB$NULL_FLAG is null for all columns

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to run a query to extract metadata of all columns in Firebird.  Here's what it looks like:

```
select
      f.RDB$RELATION_NAME as tableName,
      f.RDB$FIELD_NAME name,
      fd.RDB$FIELD_TYPE type,
      fd.RDB$FIELD_SCALE scale,
      fd.RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE subtype,
      fd.RDB$DIMENSIONS dimensions,
      fd.RDB$NULL_FLAG notNull,
      fd.RDB$FIELD_PRECISION precision
from rdb$relation_fields f
join rdb$relations r on f.RDB$RELATION_NAME = r. RDB$RELATION_NAME
join RDB$FIELDS fd on fd.RDB$FIELD_NAME = f.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE
where f.RDB$UPDATE_FLAG = 1
  and r.RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0
  and coalesce(r.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG, 0) = 0
```

For the most part, it works fine.  But for whatever reason, every single result gives `null` in the `fd.RDB$NULL_FLAG` column.  [According to the documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-fields), this value should be `null` if a column is nullable, or `1` if it is not.  (It should go without saying that I do, in fact, have some `NOT NULL` columns in my database!)

Any idea what's going wrong, and how I can get correct reporting of the nullability status of my columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check f.RDB$NULL_FLAG which overrides domain definition.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the [answer by user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68119111/466862), a field of a table is defined in two parts: an entry in `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS` for the field itself, and a domain definition in `RDB$FIELDS`. If a field is defined with a basic type instead of a (named) domain, an unnamed (numbered) domain is generated.

This unnamed domain does not have `RDB$NULL_FLAG` set, this is equivalent to `CREATE DOMAIN <domainname> <basicdatatype>`, which also does not set the `RDB$NULL_FLAG` in `RDB$FIELDS`. Instead, the `NOT NULL` constraint is recorded in `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS.RDB$NULL_FLAG`.

The `RDB$FIELDS.RDB$NULL_FLAG` is only populated with `1` when creating an explicit domain with a `NOT NULL` constraint, for example:

```sql
create domain int_not_null integer not null;
```

In short, you need to use - for example - `COALESCE(f.RDB$NULL_FLAG, fd.RDB$NULL_FLAG, 0)` to determine the nullability of the column, where `0` means nullable and `1` means not-nullable.

Similar checking of values in both tables also applies to a few other columns that exist in both `RDB$FIELDS` and `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`: `RDB$DEFAULT_VALUE`/`RDB$DEFAULT_SOURCE` and `RDB$COLLATION_ID`.